# Where are translation files stored

Tags: 14.10, translation

I want to modify a translation in the german Unity translation.

Where can I find this translation in Ubuntu 14.10?

Answer (score 0):

I think they are part of the binary packages - all my searches for `.po` files (translation files) given the result:

```
Binary file /home/tim/path/to/anarchive.zip matches
```

So if you want to edit it, you need to [edit the binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839227/how-to-edit-binary-file-on-the-unix-systems).

However, you can contribute translations to ubuntu on Launchpad. [This is translations for 14.10](https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu), and [this is translations of German for 14.10](https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu/utopic/+lang/de). You have to sign in to edit translations, and first please read this [Quick Start guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Translations/QuickStartGuide).