# Internationalisation-Translation files

Tags: language-support, translation

I have recently changed my Ubuntu into my 1st language. However, I noticed that there are some translations are not in the way I personally like them. I wish to change that translation by myself. However, when I looked at [Where are translation files stored](https://askubuntu.com/questions/554544/where-are-translation-files-stored) it didn't really make sense. I assume there's gonna be bunch of files that contain the translation strings. Does anyone know the path of these files?

Answer (score 0):

The directories, where the gettext message catalogs are usually stored on Ubuntu, are:

```
/usr/share/locale-langpack/<lang>/LC_MESSAGES

/usr/share/locale/<lang>/LC_MESSAGES
```